# Debido tanto a X como a Y/ tanto debido a X como a Y

Tags: gramática, sintaxis, concordancia-gramatical

¿Son las siguientes dos opciones gramaticalmente válidas?

1. **Debido tanto** a la pandemia **como** a la virtualidad, las medidas adoptadas son estas.
2. **Tanto debido** a la pandemia **como** a la virtualidad, las medidas adoptadas son estas.

Mi impresión es que sí, aunque quizá exista un cierto matiz de sentido que evite que puedan ser exactamente intercambiables.
En la primera oración no creo que exista duda alguna respecto a su validez gramatical, pero en el segundo caso, no estoy tan seguro. Quizá al decir **tanto debido a esto como a esto otro**, exista un ***debido*** directamente luego de **como**, pero que simplemente no es mencionado por un tema de economía del lenguaje.

En cualquier caso, me gustaría conocer la explicación gramatical de por qué ambas opciones serían gramaticalmente correctas o no.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ambas opciones son gramaticalmente válidas.

La locución preposicional "debido a" va seguida, como cualquier preposición, por un término.

Si el término es compuesto, tenemos:

- Debido a la pandemia y a la virtualidad, las medidas adoptadas son estas. (La segunda "a" puede omitirse, sobre todo cuando los elementos conforman una unidad; de lo contrario, su presencia agrega claridad.)

Con conjunciones correlativas como "tanto ... como", la segunda "a" se vuelve necesaria:

1. Debido **tanto a** la pandemia **como a** la virtualidad, ...

En (2), en lugar de coordinarse los dos componentes del término (la pandemia / la virtualidad) como en (1), se coordinan dos frases preposicionales y se produce, por economía del lenguaje, la omisión de "debido":

2. **Tanto** debido a la pandemia **como** (debido) a la virtualidad, ...